# Existence of a ball passing through points in the interior of a given ball .

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a ball $A$  in dimension $n$ and any $n$ points in $A$, can we find another ball $B$ such that all of the points lie on the boundary of $B$ and $B$ is contained in $A$?

I have a proof for the two dimensional case using elementary geometry but the general problem itself looks like a linear algebra problem.  Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I think the $n$ points have to lie on the boundary of the inner ball, and the inner ball must lie within the larger ball.

Comment: Hopefully the edits have made things clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not necessarily true.

Consider the 3-dimension case with unit sphere and 2 points inside of the sphere at $(\frac{1}{4},0,0)$, $(\frac{1}{2},0,0)$ and a third point at $(\frac{3}{4},0,0)$.

Essentially, the points that must be on the boundary of $B$ have much more constraints than they will in the 2-dimension case. Furthermore, the points must be equidistant from some other point, $p$, where $p$ is the center of our ball $B$. However, I believe if they all lie on a line inside of this ball then there is no ball, $B$, that contains all of the $n$ points on its boundary.